# Definition of an $n$-tuple agreeing with the Kuratowski's definition of an ordered pair

Tags: definition, foundations

Is there a nice and elegant definition of an $n$-tuple ($n$ is a nonnegative integer) in ZFC, which will at the same time agree with the Kuratowski's definition of an ordered pair, i.e. $\left ( a,b \right )=\left \{ \left \{ a \right \},\left \{ a,b \right \} \right \}$? I can't seem to find one.

Comment: Usually we define an ordered pair as an ordered pair, and an $n$-tuple as a function from $n$ into the set. This means that $2$-tuples are not ordered pairs.

Comment: Could you elaborate in the answer section?

Comment: I could, but not right now. If no one posts a reasonable answer in the meantime, I will write one later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer corresponding with comment of Asaf.

Define the (Kuratowski) ordered pair $\left(a,b\right):=\left\{ \left\{ a\right\} ,\left\{ a,b\right\} \right\} $ and identify
$n$ as the set $n=\left\{ 0,\dots,n-1\right\} $ (the finite ordinals) and define $n$-tuple:
$$\left\langle a_{0},\dots,a_{n-1}\right\rangle :=\left\{ \left(i,a_{i}\right)\mid i\in n\right\} $$
I deliberately use other brackets here. These sets are actually functions with domain $n$.

Now $2$-tuple $\left\langle a,b\right\rangle $
is set: $$\left\langle a,b\right\rangle=\left\{ \left(0,a\right),\left(1,b\right)\right\} =\left\{ \left\{ \left\{ 0\right\} ,\left\{ 0,a\right\} \right\} ,\left\{ \left\{ 1\right\} ,\left\{ 1,b\right\} \right\} \right\} $$
and clearly $\left\langle a,b\right\rangle \ne\left(a,b\right)$ corresponding with remark: '..$2$-tuples are not ordered pairs'.

Comment: Nice. Is this really how $n$-tuples are commonly defined?

Comment: I have not enough experience with settheory to confirm or deny that. Frankly speaking, the comment of Asaf brought me to this. I think there might be more ways to define and I don't know of the existence of one that is generally accepted. Maybe @Asaf can tell you.

Comment: It seems undesirable that $(a,b) \ne <a,b>$; if so, the $n$-tuple is not truly a generalization of the ordered pair. Also, it forces us to make a choice between whether to use $(a,b)$ or $<a,b>$ in practice. Do both definitions satisfy $(a,b)=(c,d)$ iff $a=c$ and $b=d$ and $<a,b>=<c,d>$ iff $a=c$ and $b=d$? Then in practice, which definition is chosen? For example, in defining the Cartesian product $A \times B$ of two sets $A$ and $B$, which would you use: $A \times B = \{(a,b): a \in A \wedge b \in B\}$ or $A \times B = \{<a,b>: a \in A \wedge b \in B\}$?

Comment: @EthanAlvaree Both definitions satisfy this property. If it comes to two sets then usually one chooses $(a,b)$ for the elements of the product. This even without mentioning this choice. But $n$-tuples become welcome and nice if $n>2$.

Answer (score 0):

Define the (Kuratowski) ordered pair $\left(a,b\right):=\left\{ \left\{ a\right\} ,\left\{ a,b\right\} \right\} $ and identify
$n$ as the set $n=\left\{ 0,\dots,n-1\right\} $ (the finite ordinals) and define $n$-tuple:
$$\left\langle a_{0},\dots,a_{n-1}\right\rangle :=\left(\left\langle a_{0},\dots,a_{n-2}\right\rangle,a_{n-1}\right) \tag{for $n>2$}$$

and $$\left\langle a_{0},a_1\right\rangle := \left(a_0,a_1\right) $$